# change the 5% biggest value to some value in one array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array 200x200, which value is from -600 to 100. I want to keep 95% the positive value unchanged and set the 5% biggest positive value to value at 95%. The negative is the same.

This is my code, which is so ugly that I hope to improve.

```
idx_pos = np.where(x > 0.)
idx_pos_sorted = np.argsort(x[idx_pos])
n = len(idx_pos[0])
n_punc = int(n*percentage)
x[idx_pos[0][idx_pos_sorted[n_punc:]], idx_pos[1][idx_pos_sorted[n_punc:]]] = (
  x[idx_pos[0][idx_pos_sorted[n_punc]], idx_pos[1][idx_pos_sorted[n_punc]]])
```

The histogram below is the value of array.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write it shorter you can use numpy.percentile [(numpy docs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).:

```
def cutter(data, percent):
    pc = np.percentile(data[data>0], percent)
    data[data>pc] = pc

cutter(x, 95)
x *= -1
cutter(x, 95)
x* = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the 95th percentile of all the positive values:

```
flat_x = np.sort(np.ravel(x[x > 0]))
pctl_idx = int(0.95 * len(flat_x))
pctl = flax_x[pctl_idx]
```

Then set every element larger than this to this value:

```
x[x > pctl] = pctl
```